# I am not able to run gcloud commands on lubuntu

Tags: gcloud

I Installed gcloud SDK on lubuntu-32bit system, but while running gcloud commands its giving error.

***ERROR***

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (OperationalError): database is locked

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

re-installed again but not able to figure out it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that something is keeping `gcloud`'s database open. This can be caused by numerous reasons, some possibilities and recommendations are:

- Make sure you’re not running multiple ‘gcloud’ commands in parallel, as this is currently not supported and there’s a Feature Request already open for that [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/132194628).
- Avoid installing the Cloud SDK or storing the credentials on an NFS. If you have, install the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install#installation_options) in a local directory or respectively, store the credentials in a local disk by setting the environment variable `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` to a local disk location, i.e if you’re using bash:

  `export CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/some/local/path/.gcloudconfig`
- Lastly, double check that you're using the latest version of the Cloud SDK by running [`gcloud components update`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) (although I assume you are). Alternatively, you can run [`gcloud components reinstall`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/reinstall) to attempt in fixing a corrupted Cloud SDK
  installation, which is known to have helped others in the past.

Comment: thanks, I reinstalled and restarted the system its working now.